# Позиционирование резинового сайта

Tags: jquery, javascript, html5, css

У меня вопрос, есть два блока они расположены рядом друг с другом по горизонтали и имеют одинаковую ширину, при уменьшении окна браузера или разрешения экрана один блок должен заезжать за другой за другой?

Comment: Я думаю что их ширина должна пропорционально уменьшаться а расстояние в центре между ними оставаться прежним...

Comment: Мне именно нужно чтобы один блок заезжал за другой!

Comment: а я думал Вы спрашивали наше мнения о том должен ли он заезжать :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cmNy9/). Если есть какие-то нюансы, то уточните и попробую подправить.

Comment: Я уже сделала Огромное спасибо, именно так я и решил проблему!!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/9LCUa/1/

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='first_block'></div>
  <div class='second_block'></div>
</div>
```

и css:

```
.first_block, .second_block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  border:1px black solid;
}
.first_block {
  float: left;
  border:1px green solid;  
  position: absolute;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

Если верстка резиновая, но вы хотите, чтобы блоки могли заезжать друг на друга - то размеры всё равно нужны уже не в процентном соотношении.

Comment: Спасибо Огромное!!!